writePointer Error: Waiting for Buffer Instance
I get the following error in my code:

error: error setting argument 2 - writePointer: Buffer instance expected as third argument.

(I can give more information about the code. I don't know what to write)
Below is my relevant code section:
const sectionOffset = fileAddress + 124 * 2;
      const numberOfSections = data.readInt16LE(fileAddress + 6);
      console.log("Number of departments received: " + numberOfSections);

      for (let i = 0; i < numberOfSections; i++) {
        const sectionBaseOffset = sectionOffset + i * 40;
        const virtualAddress = data.readInt32LE(sectionBaseOffset + 12);
        const sizeOfRawData = data.readInt32LE(sectionBaseOffset + 16);
        const pointerToRawData = data.readInt32LE(sectionBaseOffset + 20);

        console.log(
          `Section ${i} data: Virtual Address: ${virtualAddress.toString(16).toUpperCase()}, Raw Data Size: ${sizeOfRawData}`
        );

        if (sizeOfRawData !== 0) {
          const sectionData = Buffer.alloc(sizeOfRawData);
          data.copy(
            sectionData,
            0,
            pointerToRawData,
            pointerToRawData + sizeOfRawData
          );

          console.log(
            `Section data is being written to memory. Address: ${(newImageBase + virtualAddress).toString(16).toUpperCase()}, Size: ${sizeOfRawData}`
          );

          let bytesWritten = ref.alloc("int");
          if (
            !kernel32.WriteProcessMemory(
              openProcess,
              newImageBase + virtualAddress,
              sectionData,
              sectionData.length,
              bytesWritten
            )
          ) {
            console.log("Failed to write section to process memory.");
            throw new Error("Failed to write section to process memory.");
          }

          console.log(
            `Section ${i} has been successfully typed. Address: 0x${(newImageBase + virtualAddress).toString(16)}`
          );
        }
        sectionOffset += 40;
      }

I was expecting the following result, but I got an error instead:
Number of departments received: 3
848
8192
3261440
512
Part 0 data: Virtual Address: 2000, Raw Data Size: 3261440
Section data is being written to memory. Address: 402000, Size: 3261440
Section 0 was successfully written. Address 402000
3276800
3072
3261952
Part 1 data: Virtual Address: 320000, Raw Data Size: 3072
Section data is being written to memory. Address: 720000, Size: 3072
Chapter 1 was successfully written. Address 720000
3284992
512
3265024
Part 2 data: Virtual Address: 322000, Raw Data Size: 512
Section data is being written to memory. Address: 722000, Size: 512
Chapter 2 was successfully written. Address 722000


Which line of code exactly is raising the error?
